# Transform FlutterRenderer or SurfaceTexture

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-android

Question, I am currently struggling a bit with trying to improve the orientation of the Flutter Camera plugin specifically on Android. The problem I am facing is that when I move from portrait to landscape the preview doesn't rotate correctly (the actual captured picture or recorded video is fine). The Camera plugin uses the Android Camera2 API under the hood and researching this topic a bit it seems you can correct the rotation of the preview using the transform method of the `TextureView` as demonstrated in the Android Camera2Basic example App (see https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/4cc1c3e219d8d168b7893f7a6b2b348740679e5a/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L740).

Problem is that in the Flutter plugin I don't have access to a `TextureView`, I only have access to the `FlutterRenderer` instance and the `SurfaceTexture` that is created by the `FlutterRenderer` using the `createSurfaceTexture` method.

So my question is: is it possible to rotate or transform the `SurfaceTexture` and if so how would I approach this? Currently I can compensate for the rotation on the Dart/Flutter side by nesting the `Texture` in a RotatedBox widget. This however will mess up the orientation on the iOS side (meaning I need to use the widget conditionally based on the Platform). It also puts a bit of extra overhead on people that want to directly use the `Texture` widget in their Apps and instead of the preconfigured widget supplied from the Camera package.

Below is a screenshot demonstrating the behaviour:

[image: Android over rotation example]

Comment: Have you thought of using OpenGL for the rotation?